# Can this multidimensional non-linear equation with constraints be minimized analytically?

Tags: matrices, inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I wish to find the vector of real numbers, $\mathbf{w}$, that minimizes the function:

$$f(\mathbf{w}\mid\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})=\sum_{t=0}^T \left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^I w_ip_{ti}\right)-q_t\right]^2,$$

where $\mathbf{p}$ is a  $T \times I$ matrix of known real numbers and $\mathbf{q}$ is a vector of length $T$ containing known real numbers. Were $\mathbf{w}$ unconstrained, this is solvable by taking the necessary partial derivatives and solving the resultant system of equations; however, I'm seeking a solution wherein $\mathbf{w}$ is constrained such that:

$$w_i<w_{i+1}$$

for all $w_i$. Can this be solved analytically?

(I apologize in advance if I failed to express my question clearly. Thanks!)

Comment: First of all, as a software developper I am not a linear programmer expert. You should have noticed that this is a linearly constrained least-squares problem. And since you are constricting $w$ within a polyhedron. If the solution of the unconstrained least-squares problem lies within this polyhedron you're good. But in any other case, the solution will be on a face of the polyhedron. Which one ? It is a discrete non-continuous function of $P$ and $q$ which would invole many cases.

Answer (score 0):

After some calculation, your problem reads (p_t is a column for me):

$$ min \sum_t w^T p_t p_t^T w + 2q_t p_t^T w + q^2_t$$

$$ w_i\leq w_{i+1}$$

which is a quadratic linearly constrained optimization problem. No closed form afaik. I think the problem is convex, as $p_t p_t^T$ should be positive semi-definite. If it is not, then you have a non-convex NP-Hard problem. If it is convex, you need just a convex optimizer (as MOSEK, CPLEX). Another formulation is a conic one:

$$ min \sum_t z_t $$

$$ (1/2, z_i, p_t^T w -q_t) \in Q_r^{3}, \forall t in T$$

where $Q_r$ is a rotated quadratic cone. You need in this case a conic convex optimizer (as MOSEK).